# Create a link from Backend to SEF Path in Frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, sef, front-end, jroute

I would like to create a link in Administrator Panel that redirect a user to an SEF url in Frontend.

**Code in Backend**

```
<?php 
$link = JUri::root() . 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1';
echo '<a href="'. JRoute::_($link) . '">Test</a>'
?>
```

This can't be translated to SEF because I use `JUri::root()` in my `$link`.

If it's possible, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to JSE, please take the [tour] ...and have a good look around the place to see if you can share you knowledge with others seeking support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 3.9 there's `Joomla\CMS\Router\Route::link()` method which takes client (site or administrator) as first argument.

```
$link = 'index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1';
echo '<a href="' . JRoute::link('site', $link) . '">Test</a>';
```

If you have the article object available, you should use `ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute()` and pass the slug instead of ID to remove extra database query and also category and language to ensure correct routing.

```
// Register helper class.
JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php');

$link = ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($article->id . ':' . $article->alias, $article->catid, $article->language);
echo '<a href="' . JRoute::link('site', $link) . '">Test</a>';
```